# Java 52 card deck class making a deck, shuffling, then dealing

Tags: java

Im having troubles trying to figure this out for my class. I have a card deck class that I have to make a method to make a deck, shuffle it, then deal it to two hands. I don't know how to start them, can someone help me out please? Im a scrub at this stuff.

```
public class Game
{

public static Card[] deck = new Card[52];
public static Card[] xHand, yHand;
public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int numInHand, x=0,y=0;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Press Enter to make a new deck.");
    in.nextLine();
    makeDeck();
    System.out.println("A new deck.\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) 
        System.out.println(deck[i]);
    System.out.println("Press Enter to shuffle the deck.");
    in.nextLine();
    shuffle();
    System.out.println("\nA shuffled deck.\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) 
        System.out.println(deck[i]);
    System.out.println("How many cards would should we deal to each player?");
    numInHand = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    xHand = new Card[numInHand];
    yHand = new Card[numInHand];
    deal();
    System.out.println("\nYour Hand.\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < xHand.length; i++) 
        if(xHand[i]!=null) System.out.println(xHand[i]);
        System.out.println("\nYour Opponent's Hand.\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < yHand.length; i++) 
        if(xHand[i]!=null) System.out.println(yHand[i]);
    play();
}

public static void makeDeck()
{

}

public static void shuffle()
{

}

public static void deal()
{

}

}
```

Comment: Can you write in words _exactly_ what `makeDeck()` should do?  Then, you might have some ideas about how to translate that to Java.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Basically seems like you haven't started anything.

Comment: Try looking at this one, might give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369375/shuffling-a-deck-in-java?rq=1

Comment: I don't know how I am supposed to start the makeDeck. It's supposed to create a deck of cards in the card array and list them out. I haven't started because I don't know how to sadly

Comment: Try something. Write or talk out loud in words what needs to be done. Then do it. You know you need some cards, what ones and how many do you need?

Comment: OK.  Do you have a Card class?  What does a deck look like?  Are you going to need to do something for each suit?  For each denomination?  Will there be some loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A deck is an array (or list, or other ordered set) of cards. How you represent each card is up to you; could just be an int taken modulo 13 for value and int-divided by 4 for suit, or could be an object.

Shuffling is randomizing the order of that array or list. Simplest shuffle might be (pseudocode, assuming deck is declared as Card[]):

```
for(int i=0;i<deck.size;++i)
{
    int othercard=randomNumberFrom0To51();
    Card swap=deck[i];
    deck[i]=deck[othercard];
    deck[othercard]=swap;
}
```

Dealing: Pull the first N cards from the shuffled deck. Remember that you've done so, so further draws continue to advance through the shuffled deck.

More details may need to be defined depending on the needs of the game, but that ought to get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: this kind of helps me out with what im trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To supplement Ajay's answer please view this document on basic Array operations.
[Oracle Java Tutorials Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).